# window.onbeforeunload function is working only on page refresh but not click on anchors after IE9 to IE11 migration

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, dom-events

`window.onbeforeunload` function is working only on page refresh but not on click of anchors after IE9 to IE11 migration.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create a new web page to test the following code:

```
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">

    <p>This example demonstrates how to assign an "onbeforeunload" event to a body element.</p>

    <p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Click here to go to w3schools.com</a>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            return "Write something clever here...";
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

It works well on my machine (using IE9 and IE 11), when refreshes the page or click the anchors, it will show the prompt message that appears in a confirmation box.

If still not working, try to clear the browser cache and browser data, or [reset the browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) and repair the IE browser.

Besides, you could also add a debugger in the beforeunload function and [use the F12 developer tools to debug it](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v=vs.85)).